# WinGraph32 for the OllyFlow plugin

Tags: ida, ollydbg

I am trying to use the [OllyFlow plugin](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/178/OllyFlow) for OllyDbg 1.10. It requires WinGraph32.exe, which was apparently distributed with IDA at some point, because the [book Game Hacking](https://nostarch.com/gamehacking) says:

> Wingraph32 is not provided with OllyFlow, but it is available with the free version of IDA

It appears the current free version of IDA no longer has WinGraph32.exe included - so, how can I get the OllyFlow plugin to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about OllyFlow plugin, but here some info on WinGraph32.exe.

There was GPL-ed source code on hex-rays.com. You can download it using Internet Archive Wayback Machine. Something like this:

https://web.archive.org/web/20080901113014/http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadown.htm

Or you can download IDA Pro 5.0 Freeware which contains compiled wingraph32.exe:

https://web.archive.org/web/20110804083226/http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadown.htm

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking this would be the solution, but I was not sure which version of IDA still has this exe. And, once again, archive.org earns my donation!